# How can I animate/change the color of a torus in a-frame?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe

I am learning how to use a-frame so that I can begin diving into AR technologies. I am following a tutorial online about animating color but I am not sure if the tutorial showed me the correct way to do it as nothing appears to be animating.

I have already looked through his code in the tutorial and attempted to look at the a-frame -> a-animation documentation but still haven't had any luck

```
<a-scene>
    <a-torus position="-2 1 -5" color="green" radius="1.2">
        <a-animation attribute="color" 
            from="green" 
            to="red"
            dur="100"
            repeat="indefinite"
        ></a-animation>
    </a-torus>
    <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

It is supposed to cycle between the colors but I feel like I have been looking at this torus for minutes now and still haven't seen a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<a-animation>` element is deprecated since aframe `0.9.0`. The animation entity was made into a component.

Its pretty well documented [here](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/animation.html#sidebar), in your case, it would be:

```
<a-torus position="-2 1 -5" color="green" radius="1.2" 
      animation="property: components.material.material.color;
                 type: color;
                 to: blue;
                 dur: 500;
                 dir: alternate;
                 loop: true"></a-torus>
```

Check it out:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-torus position="-2 1 -5" color="green" radius="1.2" 
           animation="property: components.material.material.color;
                      type: color;
                      to: blue;
                      dur: 500;
                      dir: alternate;
                      loop: true">
  </a-torus>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

---

You can also use hex values - just replace `0x` with `#` (ie: `0xff00aa` -> `#ff00aa`):

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-torus position="-2 1 -5" color="#ff0000" radius="1.2" 
           animation="property: color;
                      type: color;
                      to: #0000ff;
                      dur: 500;
                      easing: linear;
                      dir: alternate;
                      loop: true">
  </a-torus>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Commenting to let people know it is still working perfectly in june 2020, since this api changes so much and things read about that work in the past often don't work in the present. +1

Comment: coming back to comment a couple years later--animating color for the first time, I'm experiencing (at least in the one case I'm trying) that I need to use hex values, not the css 'text color names' that one can often use, for colors in particular to work.

Comment: hey @KyleBaker, you can use hex values as well, I've added a `hex` snippet to the answer